# F# async equivalent of Promise.race?

Tags: asynchronous, f#

In JavaScript, there is a function called `Promise.race` that takes a list of promises and returns a new promise that completes when *any* of the input promises completes.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race

F# has `Async.Parallel`, which completes when *all* of the input asyncs have completed, but it does not seem to have an equivalent for *any* (such as `Async.Race`).

How can I write this in F#?

Comment: You could probably do something with [`Async.StartWithContinuations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/async.startwithcontinuations%5b%27t%5d-method-%5bfsharp%5d), where each of the asyncs would call the same continuation on success, and it would cancel the asyncs when it was first called. Many practical problems would need to be worked out, like the type the continuation function would take (some sort of DU), and the fact that the docs say the async would start "immediately on the current operating system thread."

Comment: Interesting that `Async` doesn't have this ability. `Task.WhenAny` in the  BCL has this behavior, if you're willing to go the `Task`-based route. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netstandard-2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use tasks.

Something like this:

```
let race (xs : Async<'t> seq) : Async<'t> =
  async {
    let! ct = Async.CancellationToken

    let! t =
      xs
      |> Seq.map (fun x -> Async.StartAsTask(x, cancellationToken = ct))
      |> Task.WhenAny
      |> Async.AwaitTask

    return! Async.AwaitTask t
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Async.Choice` from `FSharp.Control`:

```ml
let race xs = 
  async {
    let! first = 
      xs
      |> Seq.map (fun task -> async {
        let! x = task
        return Some x
      })
      |> Async.Choice

    return Option.get first
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to (ab)use the exception mechanism to get an early return.

```ml
[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]
module Async =

  open System

  /// An exception that carries a success value
  type internal ShortCircuit<'t>(value : 't) =
    inherit Exception()
    member this.Value = value

  let race (a : Async<'a>) (b : Async<'b>) : Async<Choice<'a * Async<'b>, Async<'a> * 'b>> =
    async {
      let! a = Async.StartChild a
      let! b = Async.StartChild b

      let x = 
        async {
          let! a = a

          let choice : Choice<'a * Async<'b>, Async<'a> * 'b> =
            Choice1Of2(a, b)

          raise (ShortCircuit choice)
        }
      
      let y = 
        async {
          let! b = b

          let choice : Choice<'a * Async<'b>, Async<'a> * 'b> =
            Choice2Of2(a, b)

          raise (ShortCircuit choice)
        }
      
      try 
        do! 
          Async.Parallel([| x; y |])
          |> Async.Ignore

        return failwith "Unreachable"
      with :? ShortCircuit<Choice<'a * Async<'b>, Async<'a> * 'b>> as sc -> 
        return sc.Value
    }
```

Usage:

```ml
let foo = 
  async {
    printfn "foo started"

    do! Async.Sleep 1000

    return "foo"
  }

let bar = 
  async {
    printfn "bar started"

    do! Async.Sleep 5000
    
    return "bar"
  }

async {
  printfn "Racing..."

  match! Async.race foo bar with
  | Choice1Of2 (a, b) ->
    printfn $"a = %s{a}"
    let! b = b
    printfn $"b = %s{b}"
  | Choice2Of2 (a, b) ->
    printfn $"b = %s{b}"
    let! a = a
    printfn $"a = %s{a}"
}
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```